# Overcoming HDFS-2556: unit tests directory and permissions

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to a JUnit tests on hadoop, I wrote a test case that I run on a local mini-hadoop environment using MiniDFSCluster,MiniMRCluster and JUnit.

however I'm getting this error:

```
 WARNING: Metrics system not started: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-datanode.properties, hadoop-metrics2.properties
Dec 18, 2012 4:42:29 PM org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode makeInstance
WARNING: Invalid directory in dfs.data.dir: Incorrect permission for build/test/data/dfs/data/data1, expected: rwxr-xr-x, while actual: rwxrwxr-x
Dec 18, 2012 4:42:29 PM org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode makeInstance
WARNING: Invalid directory in dfs.data.dir: Incorrect permission for build/test/data/dfs/data/data2, expected: rwxr-xr-x, while actual: rwxrwxr-x
Dec 18, 2012 4:42:29 PM org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode makeInstance
SEVERE: All directories in dfs.data.dir are invalid.
```

This looks like the HDFS bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2556 that is still pending.

Since I can't change the hadoop version i'm using, is there a way to force hadoop to accept these permissions?

I tried: 
System.setProperty("dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm", "775");
But hadoop ignores them.

Also, I can't change the permissions manually, it seems that the mini-cluster re-creates them every run.

Is there a way to overcome this without modifing hadoop or changing version?
Thanks.

Comment: Please also post the specific version of Hadoop you are using. The solution lies in configuring the ``MiniDFSCluster`` to use a proper ``dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm`` but this feature is not present in some older/maintenance/stable releases.

Comment: I had this problem on both 1.0.4 and 1.1.1. Can you please tell which hadoop version  respect this property ?

Comment: The property was added in, and is present under versions 2.x+, or in other distributions of Apache Hadoop such as CDH3 (1.x + backports) and CDH4 (2.x + backports). To set it you will need to directly set it into the configuration object you pass to the MiniDFSCluster constructor, and not via a system property.

Comment: I tried both conf.setStrings("dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm", "755");
or conf.setInt("dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm", 755);  dfsCluster = new MiniDFSCluster(conf, 1, true, null);  Both didn't help.

Comment: They will work only with a version that supports that property - did you upgrade to either of the options mentioned above before you tried this?

Comment: Maven issue, After I upgraded both hadoop-core and hadoop-minicluster + clean problem solved. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the workaround provided here,
https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@hbase.apache.org/msg52961.html

**UPDATE: Code fragment from the link (in case the link goes down)**

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c umask");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int rc = process.waitFor();
        if (rc == 0) {
            String umask = br.readLine();

            int umaskBits = Integer.parseInt(umask, 8);
            int permBits = 0777 & ~umaskBits;
            String perms = Integer.toString(permBits, 8);

            log.info("Setting dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm to " + perms);
            hBaseTestingUtility.getConfiguration().set("dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm", perms);
        } else {
            log.warn("Failed running umask command in a shell, nonzero return value ");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore errors, we might not be running on POSIX, or "sh" might not be on the path
        log.warn("Couldn't get umask", e);
    }
```

Comment: You should probably provide parts of the link in your answer because if the link goes down then your answer will help no one.